# Distinct in combination with pagination

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, pagination

Setup: MS sql 2012, EF 6.1.3, Web Api 2 and .NET 4.52

I'm currently working with a table with this layout:

[image: Table layout]

The table will eventually become very large so I need pagination when clients  are fetching the data like this:

Client <----> Web api 2 <----> Entity Framework <-----> MS SQL

So.. here is the deal. I need the latest row (highest "createdAt") of each distinct combination of Email, Brand and Type_Id 
Brand will be set for each call so I can just filter on that.

The way I do this now is like this:

```
var result = _context.Permissions.Where(p => p.Brand == brandEnum)
            .Include(p => p.Type)
            .Include(p => p.UserType)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt)
            .DistinctBy(p => new {p.Type, p.Email})
            .Skip(pageSize*(page - 1))
            .Take(pageSize);


 public static class LinqExtensions {

        public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, object> propertySelector)
        {
            return list.GroupBy(propertySelector).Select(x => x.First());
        }

    }
```

Ok, so here is the problem. This works, but is is very slow because the way it is implemented is forcing the DB to retrive all rows on every call which eventually cancles out the whole idea about pagination. Removing the "DistinctBy" filter solves the speed issue but now older (no longer valid) data will also be returned.

So I'm hoping that someone has a solution that favours both speed and functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about appending the 2 `Includes` at the end instead?

Comment: @KingKing I can't do that because DistinctBy returns a IEnumerablenot a IQueryable which I guess is part of the problem...

Comment: your `DistinctBy` method is wrong, it should be `IQueryable<>`. It is just a GroupBy then select first in each group.

Comment: @KingKing yes, but how do I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if it has better performance but that can only be checked on your side, here are some suggestions:

```
var result = _context.Permissions.Where(p => p.Brand == brandEnum)
                     .GroupBy(p => new {p.Type, p.Email})
                     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt)
                                   .FirstOrDefault())
                     .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt)
                     .Skip(pageSize*(page - 1))
                     .Take(pageSize)
                     .Include(p => p.Type)
                     .Include(p => p.UserType);
```

Comment: Hmm.. it throws this exception:Additional information: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: @iCediCe try the updated query, I'm not so sure if it is better.

Comment: @iCediCe btw, it's strange that you have that exception. I've tried some queries with `Skip` and all worked fine without using any OrderBy. What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As @KingKing suggest, you should change the `IEnumerable<T>` type by `IQueryable<T>` in your extension method:

```
  public static IQueryable<T> DistinctBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<T, object> propertySelector)
  {
        return query.GroupBy(propertySelector).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
  }
```

And this is how I would do your query:

```
var result = _context.Permissions.Where(p => p.Brand == brandEnum)
                                 .Include(p => p.Type)
                                 .Include(p => p.UserType)
                                 .GroupBy((p => new {p.Type, p.Email})
                                 .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt).FirstOrDefault())
                                 .Skip(pageSize*(page - 1))
                                 .Take(pageSize);
```

If you need to keep using your `DistincBy` method I suggest to move the `OrderByDescending` call inside of that method to order the groups:

```
  public static IQueryable<T> DistinctBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<T, object> propertySelector, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
  {
        var q=query.GroupBy(propertySelector);
        if(orderBy!=null)
          q= orderBy(q);
        return q.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
  }
```

And your query would be this way:

```
var result = _context.Permissions.Where(p => p.Brand == brandEnum)
                                 .Include(p => p.Type)
                                 .Include(p => p.UserType)
                                 .DistinctBy(p => new {p.Type, p.Email},q=>q.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedAt))
                                 .Skip(pageSize*(page - 1))
                                 .Take(pageSize);
```

The `orderBy` parameter is optional in this case.